# Want to delete the messages of a specific number from the INBOX of android

Tags: android, sms, android-service

I want to delete the messages from a specific mobile no. in android phone.
For this,I am using the following code..

The Problem in this code is that it is deleting all the conversations from the phone..
So help me please to resolve this problem.
THANX IN ADVANCE...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//  String specificPhoneNumber = "+91" ;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    long V;
    MainActivity thr = new MainActivity();
    V =thr.getThreadId(thr);
    Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/8767564523" + V);


        getContentResolver().delete(thread, null, null);


}


private long getThreadId(Context context)
    {
        long threadId = 0;

        String SMS_READ_COLUMN = "read";
        String WHERE_CONDITION = SMS_READ_COLUMN + " = 0";
        String SORT_ORDER = "date DESC";
        int count = 0;
        Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/");
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri1,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },WHERE_CONDITION,null,SORT_ORDER);

        if (cursor != null) {
                try {
                    count = cursor.getCount();
                    if (count > 0) {
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        threadId = cursor.getLong(1);                              
                    }
                } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                }
        }


        return threadId;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hello Guys,Please help Me..its very Urgent please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh...Got it ..It is Working 100%,

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

           // if(null == bundle)
             //       return;
          //  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);       
            try {
                // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
                // ITelephony getter
                tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Log.v("1","BYE BYE BYE" );
                Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
               // com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony 
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  
                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                incommingNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, incommingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("2","BYE BYE BYE" );
                for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
                {
                if ( incommingNumber.equals(BINO[i]) )
                {

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,incommingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                    //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                    Log.v("3","BYE BYE BYE" );

                //telephonyService.answerRingingCall();

                }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }
     };//BroadcastReceiver
    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
       //     setResultData(null);
           int c = (number).indexOf("YOUR NO...");
           Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(c), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           for(int i =0;i<2;i++)
           {

           if ((number).indexOf(BONO[i])!= -1)//||number.contentEquals("+917204302689")||number.contentEquals("07204302689"))
            {
                setResultData(null);
                Toast.makeText(context, "This call is not allowed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           }
        }

    }

    public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {
             Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
             //Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


                if ( bundle != null )
                {
                   // do you manipulation on String then if you can abort.



                }
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

                for (int n = 0; n <messages.length; n++) 
                {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                }
                for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
                {
                if(MINO[i].equalsIgnoreCase(smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress()))
                {
                    //abortBroadcast();
                    String Body=smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
                    if (Body.startsWith("START"))
                    {
                        Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(context,"There is START ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);toast4.show(); 
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    abortBroadcast();   
                }
                }
                // show first message
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context,"Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress()+ "\nBody: "+smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show(); 

         }
         };//BroadcastReceiver

    String incommingNumber;
    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    //private CallStateListener callStateListener;
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;
    private IncomingReceiver incomingReceiver;
    private  MessageReceiver  messageReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        //callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver  = new OutgoingReceiver();
        incomingReceiver  = new IncomingReceiver();
        messageReceiver  = new MessageReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        //tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);

         IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
         ctx.registerReceiver(incomingReceiver, filter);

         IntentFilter filter1= new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
         ctx.registerReceiver(messageReceiver, filter1);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() 
    {
        //tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(incomingReceiver);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
    }

}
```